# Jquery pegando o pai do <i>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Boas pessoal, preciso pegar o ID da tr do  que foi clicado. Meu HTML é o seguinte:

```
<table id="datatable">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Nome</th>
        <th>Data de Nascimento</th>
        <th>Telefone</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      @foreach($clients as $client)
          <tr class="editLink" id="{{ $client->id }}">
            <td>{{ $client->name }}</td>
            <td>{{ $client->birthdate }}</td>
            <td>{{ $client->phone }}</td>
            <td>{{ $client->email }}</td>
            <td class="delete delete_client"><i  class="material-icons red-text delete-tupla">delete_forever</i></td>
          </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

Estou usando o Blade do Laravel para iterar o objeto que vem do Controller, minha dúvida é o seguinte, se o usuário clicar nesta em uma `<i>`, como eu faço para o pegar o id que está na tr dele, estou tentando fazer assim:

```
$(this).closest('tr').html()
```

O JS está assim:

```
$(".delete_client").click(function(e){

  console.log($(this).closest('tr').html());

});
```

O problema é que ele pega a tr sempre da primeira iteração, se eu tiver 10 linhas, ela pega sempre a primeira, e eu preciso pegar a do que foi clicado..

Alguma dica?

Agradeço, abraços

Comment: Podes mostrar o JavaScript/jQuery que tens para além da linha que está na pergunta?

Comment: Editei ali, valeu pela dica

Comment: Use `$(this).closest('tr').attr("id")`.

Comment: O pai do `<i>`é o `td`, e o `tr`é o avô.

Comment: Repare também que fez o click no `<td>` e não no`<i>`. Confirme se isso faz diferença para o que está a tentar fazer

Comment: @Isac eu tb havia reparado isso, mas não faz diferença neste caso.

Comment: Na verdade já estava funcionando, já tinha tentado o $(this).closest('tr'), mas como estava procurando pelo .html(), obviamente ele me enviava tudo que tinha dentro do TR, quando na verdade eu precisava por o .attr('id'). Obrigado a quem respondeu!

Comment: @Hermus Posta você mesmo a resposta e depois marca como certa. Boa sorte!

Comment: @DvD sim para o `id` só não faz diferença, mas se for tentar navegar para o `parent()` ou `next()` por exemplo já fará. Convém ele ter em mente o que pretende e ter cuidado. Eu pessoalmente trocava o click para o `<i>` caso seja essa a ideia inicial em relação ao click

Comment: @Isac Eu já acho melhor no`td`, porque assim toda a área do `td` fica clicável.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A resposta do @Dvd foi a correta,

```
$(this).closest('tr').attr("id")
```

Eu estava usando o .html(), por isso estava me mostrando todo conteúdo dentro da TR e não o .attr("id") para obter o ID da tr.

Agradeço quem respondeu.

Answer (score 0):

Uma vez que estás a montar isso no PHP tens 2 possibilidades:

**Passando o ID com o PHP** com `onclick="delete("{{ $client->id }}")"`:

```
<tbody>
  @foreach($clients as $client)
      <tr class="editLink" id="{{ $client->id }}">
        <td>{{ $client->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client->birthdate }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client->phone }}</td>
        <td>{{ $client->email }}</td>
        <td class="delete delete_client" onclick="deleteRow("{{ $client->id }}")"><i  class="material-icons red-text delete-tupla">delete_forever</i></td>
      </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

Assim precisas só de ter uma função de nome `deleteRow` que recebe a ID.

**Usando JavaScript** (ou jQuery):

Aqui é mais como menos como já referiste:

```
$(".delete_client").click(function(e){
  var id = this.closest('tr').id;
  // ou com jQuery
  // var id = $(this).closest('tr').attr("id");
});
```